# Bootstrap Inputs on safari 6 not right?

Tags: input, safari, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with Twitter Bootstrap Inputs showing correctly on safari 6.0.

Im pretty sure this was fine before I moved to Mountain Lion, and it does seem to be an issue with Chrome.

Basically in Safari, the right end of the input seems cut off an is not displaying correctly. Ive taken a screen shot to demo what I mean...

Safari:

[image: Safari]

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

Any ideas?

EDIT: Just looking at the Twitter Bootstrap site and I see that alot of their inputs have the same problem!
Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: Have a look into `box-sizing`, maybe playing with the width

Comment: Note sure, cannot see how its affecting it? Quite new to this so not sure quite where to look!

Comment: Im thinking its almost certainly a Safari issue. Looking at this site, and noticed one of these badges [see here](http://cl.ly/image/1K3a3W1o2r3u) - check out the commentator badge, right side. Buttons/inputs/elements throughout bootstrap site look like that

Comment: Yeh, our site is having a lot of problems regarding the changes made in Safari 6. It's pretty annoying and quite a few other sites are showing similar problems.

Answer (score 3):

The artifact appears to be an issue with Safari's rendering of border-radius, and is not specific to Twitter Bootstrap. See [rendering borders](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4209771?start=0&tstart=0) on Apple's support forum. The inputs usually render normally after you select them.

Disabling border-radius on the affected elements with the following two lines removes the artifact. Be careful though, sometimes this causes [even more puzzling artifacts](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1409091/Screen%20Shot%202012-09-04%20at%202.18.44%20PM.png) on nearby buttons.

```
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
border-radius: 0;
```